# Webview not showing scroll bars on rotation

Tags: android, webview

When I load the WebView it shows the ScrollBar according to the current view and the content. If I rotate the Webview, then as scrollbars were not visible in portrait view it does not show them in the landscape view, even when they are required.

How can I force it to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView calculates its co-ordinates and hence determines to show scroll bar or not, at the time it is first rendered.

Those properties work only if the layout requires scrollbar in that orientation of the device

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following properties in your WebView layout to true or false to show or hide respectively:

android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalalTrack